# Using own iterators with std::string

Tags: c++, stl

I have defined my own character iterator class. Can I somehow plug it in to std::string so that I dont have to implement the std::string kind of interface again? I checked the template arguments of std::basic_string, but it does not take anything of this sort.

Comment: Why would you do something like this? What does your iterator class what `std::string`'s iterators (`char*`) don't?

Comment: My iterator is aware of character encoding, like UTF8 while std::string is not. I cant find any other c++ std::string based implementation which is aware of character encoding.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to provide `begin(std::string)` and `end(std::string)` functions which return your iterators. These can then be used in all the places which expect iterators.

`begin()` free function style is [from c++11 onwards](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin).

Comment: You can put these functions in your own namespace, but would they be found? Argument Dependent Lookup will not search _your_ namespace.

Comment: @MSalters  is there a reason it will not search my namespace? It doesnt need to be in a namespace, global namespace should do.

Comment: This is just a special case of "Custom specializations of std::begin may be provided for classes that do not expose a suitable begin() member function, yet can be iterated." right?

Comment: Not if you're talking about `begin(std::string)`, because that class _does_ expose a suitable `.begin()` member.

Answer (score 0):

There's an overloaded constructor for std::string which will take an iterator pair. That would work, but create a copy. That is of course the best you can do. Consider an implementation which has the "Small String Optimization", i.e. a small `char[N]` inside the `std::string` object itself. That is very, very likely incompatible with your memory layout.